# How can I prevent reload when I hit F5

Tags: java, applet, refresh, keyboard-events

I don't want to reload my Java applet when I press F5, but I want my application to use F5 key.

I want the user to use F5 for his use - I don't want to disable F5 key in my applet, but when he presses F5, the Applet should not reload.

I found that when ever we are refreshing,  the Applet stop method is called. but it should not happen.

Comment: I think you need more detail in your question, like which technologies are you using? Are you talking about a Java Applet?

Comment: There is no way to isolate an applet from a page reload, the applet will be reloaded if that is what the browser was going to do (short of bugs where the browser **never** reloads the applet).  But perhaps a better question(s) are:  What are you attempting to achieve by doing this?  What is it you want to offer the end user through preventing the applet reload?  It seems you are pursuing a flawed strategy to attain (what is presumably) a noble goal.  What is the goal?

Answer (score 2):

Use another key combination for your applet (e.g. Ctrl-F5).  The user needs F5 to refresh the web page.